# Cardinality of set difference of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Is $|A \setminus B| = |A| - |A \cap B|$, where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, true? I have been unable to prove this or find a good reference on cardinality of set differences. The only reference I found was [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Complement), and the only case they consider is when $A \subseteq B$, which is not necessarily the case here.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem by noticing that $A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap B)$. You then indeed only need to consider $B \subseteq A$. You could then proceed by induction on the number of elements of $B$ (since $A \setminus (B_1 \cup B_2) = (A \setminus B_1) \setminus B_2$).

Answer (score 7):

Let A, B be sets, where A is finite. $x \in A \Rightarrow (x \in A$ and $ x \not \in B$) or ($x \in A$ and $ x\in B )\Rightarrow $ $x \in A \setminus B$ or $x \in A \cap B$.

Hence

Clearly if $x \in A \setminus B$ or $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$. So we have established that

$ A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$

Now since $A \cap B$ and $A \setminus B$ are disjoint, then we have that 
$\lvert A \rvert = \lvert A \cap B \rvert + \lvert A  \setminus B \rvert$.